# ¿Cómo cambiar el idioma de las excepciones a inglés?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excepciones

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto con la interfaz de usuario en inglés. El problema es cuando salta una excepción el mensaje descriptivo de la misma me sale en español.

He intentado cambiar las opciones del ensamblador, el archivo de configuración web.conf y hasta me he bajado el paquete de idioma del Visual en inglés y sigo sin dar con "la solución".

Este es el web.config que tengo:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules>
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
  </system.codedom>

  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="AsteriskEventsDBEntitiesLogin" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="eventsEntities" connectionString="" />
<add name="AsteriskVulnerabilitiesDBEntities" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda posible, esto me está causando bastantes días de atraso en el proyecto.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Añade tambíen esto: <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y nada...

Comment: @Ace, esta es una [opción](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17845078/4092887) o busca `c# change exception message language` en Google. si encuentras la solución, por favor, publica y acepta tu propia respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Podrías mirar en tus páginas que no cambies la cultura a es-ES? Busca en el proyecto cambios de este tipo. Mira este link (en inglés) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209133/exception-messages-in-english

Comment: @ PHX255 Sí, ya lo había comprobado y la app únicamente está en inglés y en ningún momento cambio la cultura. Ese link ya lo había mirado y tampoco me ayudó a encontrar la solución, pero gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: @Mauricio Arias Olave Esa opción la había probado pero también sin éxito... si logro encontrar la solución ten por seguro que lo publicaré. Gracias de todos modos!

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que lo toma del idioma del S.O. en casos anteriores en mi maquina salen los mensajes en español, pero al montarlo en el server que tiene el S.O. en ingles, los mensajes de excepcion me aparecen tambien en ingles.

Saludos.